# Combination of GridSearchCV's refit and scorer unclear

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I use `GridSearchCV` to find the best parameters in the inner loop of my nested cross-validation. The 'inner winner' is found using `GridSearchCV(scorer='balanced_accuracy'`), so as I understand the documentation the model with the highest balanced accuracy on average in the inner folds is the 'best_estimator'. I don't understand what the different arguments for `refit` in `GridSearchCV` do in combination with the `scorer` argument. If `refit` is True, what scoring function will be used to estimate the performance of that 'inner winner' when refitted to the dataset? The same scoring function that was passed to `scorer` (so in my case 'balanced_accuracy')? Why can you pass also a string to `refit`? Does that mean that you can use different functions for 1.) finding the 'inner winner' and 2.) to estimate the performance of that 'inner winner' on the whole dataset?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `refit=True`, sklearn uses *entire* training set to refit the model. So, there is no test data left to estimate the performance using any `scorer` function.

If you use multiple `scorer` in GridSearchCV, maybe `f1_score` or `precision` along with your `balanced_accuracy`, sklearn needs to know which one of those `scorer` to use to find the "inner winner" as you say. For example with `KNN`, `f1_score` might have best result with `K=5`, but `accuracy` might be highest for `K=10`. There is no way for sklearn to know which value of hyper-parameter `K` is the best.

To resolve that, you can pass one string `scorer` to `refit` to specify which of those `scorer` should ultimately decide best hyper-parameter. This best value will then be used to retrain or refit the model using full dataset. So, when you've got just one `scorer`, as your case seems to be, you don't have to worry about this. Simply `refit=True` will suffice.

Comment: Do you have any hints on how to actually have this working in action? I have asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533647/gridsearchcv-with-scoring-function-and-refit-parameter

Comment: refit=True, sklearn uses entire training set to refit the model... But does it also gives you the scores of the cross-validation used to find the best hyperparameters?