# GridSearchCV with Scoring Function and Refit Parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

My question seems to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591311/combination-of-gridsearchcvs-refit-and-scorer-unclear) but there is no solid answer there.

I'm doing a multi-class multi-label classification, and for doing that I have defined my own scorers. However, in order to have the `refit` parameter and get the best parameters of the model at the end we need to introduce one of the scorer functions for the refit. If I do so, I get the error that `missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_pred'`. y_pred should be the outcome of fit. But not sure where this issue is coming from and how I can solve it.

Below is the code:

```
scoring = {'roc_auc_score':make_scorer(roc_auc_score),
          'precision_score':make_scorer(precision_score, average='samples'),
          'recall_score':make_scorer(recall_score, average='samples')}

params = {'estimator__n_estimators': [500,800],
          'estimator__max_depth': [10,50],}

model = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_jobs=4)
model = MultiOutputClassifier(model)

cls = GridSearchCV(model, params, cv=3, refit=make_scorer(roc_auc_score), scoring = scoring, verbose=3, n_jobs= -1)

model = cls.fit(x_train_ups, y_train_ups)
print(model.best_params_)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `refit="roc_auc_score"`, the name of the scorer in your dictionary.  From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> For multiple metric evaluation, this needs to be a `str` denoting the scorer that would be used to find the best parameters for refitting the estimator at the end.

Using a callable for `refit` has a different purpose: the callable should take the `cv_results_` dict and return the `best_index_`.  That explains the error message: sklearn is trying to pass `cv_results_` to your auc scorer function, but that function should take parameters `y_true` and `y_pred`.